# How can I access remotely a postgres database hosted on a raspberry pi (docker) using cloudflare tunnel?

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, raspberry-pi, cloudflare

I am trying to access my postgres database remotely, which is hosted on a docker container on my raspberry pi 4. I would like to be able to connect to it through python using something like:

```
import psycopg2
connection = psycopg2.connect('postgres://user:password@db.mydomain.com:5432/mydbname')
```

The database is actually timescaledb, but should work in the same way as postgres.

I am currently able to access when on my network just by pointing the connection to the internal ip of my raspberry:

```
connection = psycopg2.connect('postgres://user:password@192.168.1.***:5432/mydbname')
```

I have installed cloudflared via docker on the raspberry and configured a tunnel by pointing db.mydomain.com to the internal ip address 192.168.1.***:5432 using TCP.
Following [this guide](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/applications/non-http/arbitrary-tcp/), I have also installed cloudflared on the client machine (windows) and run in cmd:

```
cloudflared access tcp --hostname db.mydomain.com --url localhost:5432
```

I tried using HTTP or HTTPS as Service type in cloudflare but nothing seems to work, although I am able to access other containers like portainer on the raspberry through the same tunnel with no problems.

The error I get in python is:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "db.mydomain.com" (104.2*.**.***), port 5432 failed: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

104.21.**.*** seems to be a Cloudflare ip address.

Would anybody be so kind to help me solve this issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a cloudflare tunnel at the origin, so that the sql traffic is proxied.

Here is an example to ssh through terminal a Raspberry remotely:
https://youtu.be/fNSf7D8CXgA

I hope it helps.